# What do I have to do prior to site creation of a “Report center” template?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, central-administration, reporting-services, reports

I have a SSRS service installed, I have Sharepoint 2010 Enterprise Edition.

As I read on the internet, I should activate the Report Server Central Administration Feature in site settings > Manage site features, but it's not present.

Does anyone know what I should do to make it appear in the list?

Comment: What version of SSRS are you using? 2008 R2 or 2012?

Answer (score 1):

If you have correctly integrated Reporting Services with SharePoint through the Central Admin, the mentioned below features are automatically activated as a site collection features in existing site collections in the farm.

Report Server Integration Feature
Reporting

After the activation, you can validate this when you go to Site Settings > Reporting Services 
Manage Shared Schedules 
Reporting Services Site Settings

So far, this only validates that Reporting Services are ready to be used in your SharePoint environment. In order to use reports, you need to create a Report Library and you need to add these additional content types to the library through library settings :-

Report Builder Model
Report Builder Report
Report Data Source

All of the above steps are correctly explained here:- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/88285/Integrating-Sharepoint-2010-and-SQL-Reporting-Serv

Answer (score 0):

please refer to this to activate the feature:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677366.aspx

and

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010setup/thread/4b0d6f6f-9aba-4c35-9975-9756dd2c8a27

hope this helps :)